# Sql statement insight

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
 UPDATE Tnm_Lookup SET
    P_C = 'C'
    where Tnm_Lookup_ID in (select top (355) Tnm_Lookup_ID from Tnm_Lookup where 
Tnm_Lookup_ID = Tnm_Lookup_ID order by Tnm_Lookup_ID DESC);
```

I don't understand why this statement worked before and now it will no longer update my table. Can anyone give me some insight why this is not working?

Comment: Are there any records where `P_C = NULL`?  If you run the subquery by itself does it return any records?

Comment: By "not working" do you mean it does nothing or SQL Server reports an error? If it's an error, what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first posting, it looks as you only wanted to update `P_C` if it was `null`. In that case use `P_C is null`. A null value is never equal (=) to anything including another null. You have to use `is null`.

```
UPDATE Tnm_Lookup 
SET P_C = 'C'
where Tnm_Lookup_ID in (
select top (355) Tnm_Lookup_ID 
from Tnm_Lookup 
where P_C is NULL 
order by Tnm_Lookup_ID DESC)
```

If you search for `Tnm_Lookup_ID` only in the top 355 rows of the *entire* table in descending order, then if `Tnm_Lookup` has a lot of rows, you're likely to miss the one you want. `where P_C is null` helps because you're only returning the rows where `P_C` hasn't been updated yet.

Still, it's risky to restrict the search to a fixed number unless you know for sure there will never be more than 355 rows waiting for update.

Why the 355? If just for efficiency then it's not worth speeding up search if it's going to miss cases.

Is this what you wanted?

```
UPDATE Tnm_Lookup SET P_C = 'C'
where P_C is NULL
```

If I've guessed wrong, then you should edit the question to explain the `top (355)`.

Answer (score 2):

well does this return any records?

```
select top (355) Tnm_Lookup_ID 
from Tnm_Lookup 
where P_C = NULL 
order by Tnm_Lookup_ID DESC
```

Comment: It does not I had the wrong query in the post. I updated. Now this works I never change any thing in the table.

Comment: Really you have "where Tnm_Lookup_ID = Tnm_Lookup_ID" in the *real* query?

Comment: User251.. should give paparazzi credit if answering. He pointed out that the subquery was not returning any rows to update.

Comment: @user2516641, I think, that Paparazzi wanted to point out that this `where Tnm_Lookup_ID = Tnm_Lookup_ID` is like `WHERE 1=1`. You probably wanted to put something like `where Tnm_Lookup_ID = Tnm_Lookup.ID` to take one value from your outer and one from your inner query... (+1 from my side)